# Text formatting buttons make text scroll out of view

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The text formatting buttons which physically insert characters into a question/answer field make the cursor snap out of view, disrupting typing, and leading to odd looks like this:

[image: App post formatting]

To reproduce/make it a little clearer what I mean:

1. Create a question/answer with enough text to require scrolling.
2. Insert e.g. a numbered list, from the formatting bar.

Looks like it may be snapping to the top of the keyboard, with no regard for the predictive-block and formatting toolbar?

This is iPhone 4s, iOS 8.1.2, and app v1.2.1.

Comment: And apologies for the recent barrage of posts, have got round to writing up a few problems I've come across over the last few weeks!

Comment: I think as long as they are problems you should be okay (I've about 10/11 more problems I've to post when I get a chance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next release.

Part of the problem stemmed from bad behavior in `UITextView`.  It appears that when you call `setText:` the view will purge all of the rendered text layers and then incorrectly calculate the content height on a CoreAnimation rendering pass.  It then calculated the correct one on the next pass, resulting in a flicker and out of place content.  After a lot of trial and error I was able to compress the steps by [forcing an offscreen rendering and a layout event](https://github.com/bnickel/SEMarkdownEditor/commit/f6573f5e162b8ecf7dd010fd389464b89c9a9b22).

This worked well in `PSPDFTextView` managing its own scrolling but terribly in our app where the text view is hosted in a scroll view for the title and tag fields.  Right now I've got a functional but ugly hack working and am hoping to have something better eventually.

> [image]